# Visual Studio 2013 Test Explorer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, moq, mstest

I have created a simple C#/.Net solution with 2 projects:

- A Class Library.
- A Unit test project with a single UnitTest class, and I have added Moq to this project.

I then created three UnitTest methods, that use Moq to mock a single class, that is then injected into another class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace MockSimple.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<ClassImplementingFunctionality>();
            mock.Setup(functionality => functionality.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(4);
            var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mock.Object);
            classUnderTest.Method(2,2);
            mock.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Exactly(1));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<ClassImplementingFunctionality>();
            mock.Setup(functionality => functionality.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(0);
            var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mock.Object);
            classUnderTest.Method(10,5);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod3()
        {
            var ints = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
            var mock = new Mock<ClassImplementingFunctionality>();
            mock.Setup(functionality => functionality.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(4);
            var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mock.Object);
            classUnderTest.LoopInts(ints);
            mock.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Exactly(ints.Count));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod4()
        {
            var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -2, -7 };
            var mock = new Mock<ClassImplementingFunctionality>();
            mock.Setup(functionality => functionality.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(4);
            var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mock.Object);
            classUnderTest.LoopInts(ints);
            mock.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Exactly(4));
        }

    }
}
```

But when trying to run the test methods using the builtin test-manager in VS2013, I get the following error in the the Test Output Window:

> ```
> ------ Run test started ------
> The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
> Value does not fall within the expected range.
>  Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection'.
>  Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection'.
>  Element: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection' -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection
>  Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection'.
>  Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Model.TestGroupCollection
>  ========== Run test finished: 4 run (0:00:00,3464634) ==========*
> ```

I can easily run the test-methods using Resharper Unit Test Framework.

For Me it looks like MSTest is trying to do some Dependency Injection or looking for either MEF or Unity configuration.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does this issue show up for a new unit test project? If yes, then can you try delete/rename this folder: `%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache` and restart VS.

Comment: Yes - the error also shows up for a new project, and deleting the cache file as described doesn't help.

Comment: I think it might be a setting related to the Test Explorer Window that has corrupted. I'm still able to debug the test methods.

Comment: Test Explorer uses settings from *.runsettings file, it should not cause MEF composition errors as runsettings is parsed after the initialization. Can you check if there is a VS addin that's causing this? To do that, open an experimental VS instance: in Developer Command Prompt run `devenv /rootSuffix exp`, see if the issue repros there. If it still repros, VS installation repair may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graci, Graci...

> in Developer Command Prompt run devenv /rootSuffix exp

The command above solved the problem :-)